# UserScript - Empty error console in Opera

Tags: javascript, debugging, greasemonkey, opera-dragonfly

I'm writing a UserScript (=Greasemonkey) which I am developing in FireFox but works in Opera, FF and Chrome. I changed my entire script in Firefox, replacing all texts with variables as to be able to port the script easily to other languages. Now it no longer runs in Opera and it doesn't show any errors in the console (Dragonfly). The script does nothing at all, so there must be some syntax error that Firefox can handle but Opera not.

I do not use any specific FireFox features (GM_*), as I said: I only replaced strings in the scripts with variables defined in a new "translation" array.

Code to insert my script:

```
(
 function()
 {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + myFunctionName + ")()";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
 }
)();
```

So...

- Is there some JavaScript stuff that Firefox can handle but Opera not?
- Or can I get the error console to work for a UserScript?

I did some googling and searched these forums but couldn't find anything that worked...

PS: I posted this on the Opera forums first but figured I have a much better chance getting a way to find a "debugging work-around" on SOF.

PPS: In the meanwhile I also tried locating the problem with JS Lint but that one gives an error when you as much as sneeze.

Comment: `script.textContent = "(" + myFunctionName + ")()";` is poor form and *might* be part of the problem (I don't dev on Opera).  this would be better as `script.textContent = "(" + myFunctionName.toString() + ")()";`

Comment: Someone else told me to drop the .toString() as it was default behavior in the context?

Comment: It is the behavior of at least some browsers.  I do not know if it is part of the spec.  But, dropping the toString() obfuscates what the code is supposed to do -- always a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message console (Ctrl+Shift+O) should contain errors from UserScripts. Alternatively, you could try packaging your script into an extension and use Dragonfly for debugging: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/converting-userjs-to-extensions/

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O is not known on http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.50/en/keyboard.html

Comment: (Couldn't edit previous post anymore) I've converted the UserJS to an oex file and I'm trying to find the error now...

Comment: It works now. Using "return" as a field on an object apparently wasn't such a good idea. I never managed to see any error in the Opera errorconsole though. And misusing return in that context doesn't bother Firefox one bit...

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O is not listed there, but it's included in both default key configurations. Alternatively, that error console can be found via Opera->Page->Developer Tools->Error Console